# Is there a general animation function in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Do you know a function in tkinter to change a general parameter of a widget over time (or for loop)? Like the move function changes its coordinates automatically.Is there something similar with which I could change the extent=x parameter of an arc over a for loop? Or should I write it for myself?

Update:

After your answer Bryan Oakley, I came up with this:

```
def rotate_arc_function():
    for d in range(90, 359):
        arc.configure(extent=d)
        root.update()
        time.sleep(.05)
```

But the arc object I get with

```
arc = canvas.create_arc(20,20,100,100, extent=90, fill="green")
```

doesn't seem to have the configure function, because I get: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'configure'

Comment: ovals don't have an `extent` parameter. Did you mean "arc"?

Comment: oh, yes sorry, i edit the question

Comment: an arc isn't a widget, so it won't have the configure method.

Comment: using `time.sleep` is an anti-pattern. It will cause your entire program to freeze, making it less responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after` method can call a function after a given amount of time. To have it run repeatedly, have the function call `after` each time it is called.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_arc(10, 10, 190, 190, extent=0, outline="red", tags=("arc",))

def change_extent():
    extent = float(canvas.itemcget("arc", "extent"))
    extent = extent + 5.0
    canvas.itemconfigure("arc", extent=extent)
    canvas.after(100, change_extent)

change_extent()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, based on your abstract hint I came up with a try (see update), but it doesn't work. I think it is independent of the question whether I use after() or the time library. Do you see a solution?